# Converting tf.gradients to tensor type

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.14.0. I would like to know how I can type cast list into tensor. I get this error when trying to use tf.convert_to_tensor(). Appreciate any help

***Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.***

Here is my code

```
def testtf4():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
    op = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,3])

    print("\nshape of x,y", x.shape, y.shape)
    arr = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Data\\Training_and_codes\\ML\\TF Samples\\Data.csv", delimiter=",");
    gradmulx_op = tf.gradients(op[:,0],x)
    gradmuly_op = tf.gradients(op[:,0],y)
    tgradmulx_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(gradmulx_op)
    tgradmuly_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(gradmuly_op)
    print("\nshape of gradmul tensors", tgradmulx_op.shape, tgradmuly_op.shape)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print("started session......\n")
        input_feed={}
        input_feed[x]=arr[:,0]
        input_feed[y]=arr[:,1]
        input_feed[op]=arr[:,2:4]
        [gradx, grady] = sess.run([tgradmulx_op, tgradmuly_op],input_feed)
        print("x gradient",gradx) 
        print("y gradient",grady)
```

Comment: There are multiple problems here, there is no need to convert gradients to tensor, they are already tensors. tf.gradients returns None because there is no gradient to compute between two unrelated placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think in 1.14 tf.gradients returns list (https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.14/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/gradients.md). This is just a sample code to reproduce an error I get in bigger project where I use tf.gradients to construct loss function. I want to use return from tf.gradients for some matrix operations with other tensors. If I use it as it is error pops up that Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, None, None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Comment: Sure, it returns a list of tensors, so I do not see the problem. You really need to describe the real problem, because I do not get now what is the problem since you have obscured it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not have to do with `tf.convert_to_tensor`, but with the fact that your are trying to compute some gradients that do not exist. You have these two placeholders:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
op = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
```

And then you try to get the following gradients:

```py
gradmulx_op = tf.gradients(op[:, 0], x)
gradmuly_op = tf.gradients(op[:, 0], y)
```

For these gradients to exist (that is, not be `None`), the value of `op[:, 0]` would have to be the result of one or more differentiable operations using `x` and `y`. For example, if `op` were defined as:

```py
op = tf.stack([2 * x + 3 * y, x - 1, 2 * y + 2], axis=1)
```

Then it would work, because `op[:, 0]` would be computed from `x` and `y` (and possibly other values), so there is a gradient between the tensors. Or, put it a different way, changing `x` or `y` changes the value of `op[:, 0]`. TensorFlow keeps track of the operations used to compute each value and uses that information to automatically compute the gradients.

But `op` is not calculated from `x` and `y`, in fact it is not calculated from anything, since it is a placeholder, it is just a given value. A change in `x` or `y` does not entail a change in `op`. So there is no gradients between those tensors. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your code, but you probably need to rethink what exactly is the result that you want to compute.

Comment: Thanks. Sample code works now. Also my original model which led me to write this sample had missing feature in network graph